# How do I import Test case and it's steps from Excel/CSV to Zephyr on JIRA cloud?

Tags: jira

I am trying to import test case and it's steps from CSV file to JIRA cloud. I have installed Zephyr plugin on JIRA and am able to create test case and steps manually.

But I have thousands of test cases and related steps from my other SQL based system, adding them manually is not an option. Any pointers on this?

Comment: Hi Amit Sahu. Why exactly you can't import from the CSV? It's not clear what have you done with Zephyr and if you're getting any error.

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica Hello, I  was playing around and found a utility Zephyr Import Utility, which expects the test steps and test case in Excel file or XML format. Then it imports the test cases and related steps to JIRA. Figured out that Zephyr is creating a Issue type called "Test" and hence the data import process is same as normal JIRA issue import as well. Hope this helps in case anyone needs more info. I got this link : https://support.smartbear.com/kb/how-do-i-import-test-cases-into-zephyr-for-jira-se/

Comment: So you don't have a problem anymore?

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica Thanks for following up ! I was able to pass this one , but now different issue. I think it's a tough journey to migrate from one system to another :(

Comment: Feel free to write as an answer how you solved this one and if you have another question don't do it here in this one. Instead, ask a new one but always remember to explain the problem clearly, what have you done to try and fix it,... SO encourages users to ask questions as long as they have quality :-)

Comment: I really like jira but I believe this question is way too-specific, software oriented rather than pm problem to be a good fit for pm.se.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JIRA API: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/

The special format used in your CSV files is most likely not supported by any existing import tool, so you will have to write your own. You should be able to do that in any programming language you're familiar with, provided it or libraries available for it support CSV file parsing, RESTful interface access and preferably OAuth for authentication, although that isn't strictly required. Python would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: Using JIRA API will be too much for this need. It's simple CSV import process, it seems. For that purpose writing the API will be an overkill. Thanks for your response though, at least we know, that we have a API route as well :)